# Android: How to remove borders around navview menu items?

Tags: android, menu, drawerlayout, navigationview

Using android studio 2.1.2 I added navigation activity from standard library. It inflates menu with some default items:

[image: screenshot from my phone]

How can I remove those borders from menu items?

Device:
Asus padfone 2
Android 4.1.1

Compilation:
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0